# sysinternals help file not working

Tags: chm, sysinternals

Using Windows 10 on recently downloaded sysinternals.

Question

Using File Explorer to start help files (*.chm)
Eg procmon.chm.  Help file loads but page contents blank
The Contents, index and search options work but e.g. the Content detail is not displayed on the right hand screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each .chm file has a security option.

Use Explorer to browse to the .chm file, 
Go to properties at the bottom of the window
Security "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect the computer"

Tick the Unblock box, Apply and the help file will now work correctly.

More details here [Microsoft: Unblocking sysinternals.zip](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/delay/p/unblockingdownloadedfile/)

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.

Comment: Mark's website should warn people to turn off blocking after downloading any Sysinternals Zip file.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a 3 step process - Open the Property sheet, Click Unblock box on the General tab,  then OK  - get an error dialog, Click "Try again", Click on "Continue" to confirm Admin privileges.  After this the Help info appears as it should.